# Meaning of "symbolic narrative"

Tags: meaning

What is a "symbolic narrative"?

I know a narrative is a story. But what exactly is a symbolic narrative?

Upon Googling, I have found that allegories and myths are symbolic narratives, but no real definition of what constitutes a symbolic narrative itself.

For some context, I have some reading comprehension exam study material and we are given a passage and asked to categorise it as a 1) logical abstraction, 2) personal reflection, 3) symbolic narrative, or 4)philosophical argument. But I can't figure out the exact meaning of symbolic narrative.

Comment: I'm guessing they simply mean *allegory*.

Comment: Probably a narrative that doesn't specifically say that its an allegory but that _they_ interpret as an allegory. I.e. a narration that many people might take as a simple narration but _they_ don't.  For instance, the creation story in Genesis. Is it an allegory? Is it not an allegory? In an academic context it will probably be _treated as_ an allegory regardless what many readers might think to the contrary.

Comment: An even better example. Mark Twain's "The Fly."  It seems to me like a simple philosophical argument: _If a human being had created flies we'd put him in prison; flies only spread disease, etc. but since God created flies, we don't do nothing about it._  But my English teacher back in high school *insisted* that this was an allegory. She claimed that God represented man and flies represented guns; and I argued with her, "then what does man represent?"  Nothing of course; because its not an allegory, but she _had to_ have it be one.

Comment: It's a narrative that stands symbolically for something else. For example, Little Red Riding Hood could be a symbol of innocence. Ergo, the story of Little Red Riding Hood could be seen as a symbolic narrative. A narrative that stands for something else. Not a literal story. For example, Huck Finn is not a symbolic narrative.

Comment: @developerwjk Damn leftist teachers, eh?

Comment: @Lambie, If Little Red Riding Hood is symbolic, why isn't Huck Finn? Its very subjective. Its all a projection of the teacher's ideology. So on these tests, you have to guess based on the known ideology of the test makers. Simple as that.

Comment: Little Red Riding Hood is the kind of story that begins: Once upon a time, Huck Finn begins: I'm Huck Finn. You don't know about me unless you read the Adventures of Tom Sawyer. So, the first is a fairy tale and the second is in the tradition of realist literature, which is not considered symbolic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus on the word *narrative* rather than *symbolic* and it might be more clear. Thus, essentially you'd recognize such passages as those primarily meant to tell a story (likely to make a point, given the context, but not necessarily) as opposed to 1) identifying and discussing some common elements among some things; 2) a self-exploring discussion (these should be relatively obvious); or 4) a broader philosophical discussion.  The key is to not confuse narratives for philosophical arguments just because they may be trying to make a point, or conversely, get thrown off by passages that use some sort of allegorical example (i.e., something "symbolic," like mythology) to illustrate a philosophical issue.  At their cores, narratives are stories, and philosophical discussions are arguments/debates/etc.